# GoalSeek in VBA Run-Time Error '1004': Application Defined or Object Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am working on a production model that looks at if we have 'EmployeeCount' of Staff, how much production can we do. I have built a model that works for the exercise but it requires a lot of goal seeking to get to desired staff counts. When I do the goal seek function outside of VBA, it works, but I am trying to use VBA to speed up the process. Here is my code:

```
Sub GoalSeek()
  Worksheets("Staffing Model").Activate

  Dim A As Long
  Dim EmployeeCount As Range
  Dim Reference As Range
  Dim Target As Double

 Target = 0
 For A = 7 To 60
 Set EmployeeCount = Cells(277, A)
 Set Reference = Cells(20, A)
 EmployeeCount.GoalSeek Target, Reference

 Next A

End Sub
```

Answers start in column G20
row 20 is value
row 277 is a formula for variance
I am trying to get to 0 variance

When I step through I get to the Goal Seek and it returns

> "Run-time error '1004': Application-Defined or Object-defined error

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know much about Goalseek but you haven't set the _EmployeeCount_ range.

Comment: You Dimmed `EmployeeCount` but you never `Set` it to anything, so you cannot use `GoalSeek`

Comment: I have revised the code above to reflect what I currently have. EmployeeCount is set and the error continues.

Comment: Does your Cells(277, A) even depend on Cells(20, A)? Have you tried Solver instead?

Comment: Revising earlier typo: Yes, cell (277,A) does depend on (20,A). Doing Goal Seek manually works but the code is not working. I am hoping to use goal seek so I can run other simulations quickly, as well. I have a different loop that changes variables and then reruns the simulation.

Comment: On a blank sheet ... A2 is formula =A4/100; A4 is constant 15; A5 is constant 10. `Sub GoalSeek() Set Dep = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1) Set Ind = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 1) Dep.GoalSeek Goal:=150, ChangingCell:=Ind End Sub`  ..Cell A5 changes to -3355433.2 ... I could trace [GoalSeek Method Excel 2003 VBA Language Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa195749(v=office.11)) (07/11/2006) but that method is not mentioned in latest (08/14/2019) [Range object (Excel) Methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)#methods)

Comment: @Naresh When I use the code above and apply it to the existing model, (Set Dep = ActiveSheet.Cells(277,7) Set Ind = ActivateSheet.Cells(20,7) Dep.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Ind it works. So have I screwed something up with setting up the loop?